# Itext signing PDF hash. code error 0x2727

Tags: java, pdf, hash, cryptography, itext

I am having trouble digitally signing a pdf hash. This is the implementation and the solution I have found, which is based on Bruno Lewagie's Digital Signatures for PDF Documents. The idea is to sign the PDF hash to avoid taking it to the client.
This is the solution I have come up with:

**1.** An Applet Java with which I instance a token, get it, and then access it.

**2.** A servlet java I use to get the hash of the PDF I want to sign. I calculate the hash with the public key I got from the applet. After getting this hash, I send it to the applet (client) to get it signed.

The applet signs the resulting PDF hash and then returns it to the servlet to be inserted in the resulting PDF and saved in a given directory.
At first, it seemed to work out all right, but after completing the process and opening the PDF with any reader, I get the following error: "Internal cryptografic error. Error code: 0x2727". 
It is worth mentioning that when I creat a PDF and sign it only with the applet, the signature is correctly validated.

Code: 
Applet that interacts with the token and invokes the servlet **->**

```
public void clientCallServlet(Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk) {
// Send to servlet cert
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(aConnection.getOutputStream());
  out.writeObject(chain[0]);
  out.flush();
  out.close();

  List<String> cookies = aConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
  // received hash pdf from servlet       
  InputStream is = aConnection.getInputStream();
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] data = new byte[256];
  int read;
  while ((read = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    baos.write(data, 0, read);
  }
  is.close();
  // Sign bytes hash received
  Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
  sig.initSign(pk);
  sig.update(baos.toByteArray());
  data = sig.sign();
  // End to sign 

  // send signed hash to servlet (second step)
    ...
    ...
  // Write the signed bytes received from servlet  in a PDF 
  File someFile = new File("c:/test1.pdf");
  OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] data1 = new byte[256];
  int read1;
  while ((read1 = retornoFirmado.read(data1)) != -1) {
    baos1.write(data1, 0, read1);
  }
  retornoFirmado.close();
  byte[] firmado = baos1.toByteArray();

  fos.write(firmado);
  fos.flush();
  fos.close();
```

}

Servlet that after having received the public key of the certificate (sent by the applet) reads a PDF and calculates its hash to return it to the applet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
ObjectInputStream resultStream = null;
  resultStream = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
  Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[1];
  chain[0] = (Certificate) resultStream.readObject();
  resultStream.close();

  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:/test.pdf");
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0');

  PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
  sap.setReason("Test");
  sap.setLocation("On a server!");
  sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
  sap.setCertificate(chain[0]);
  PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
  dic.setReason(sap.getReason());
  dic.setLocation(sap.getLocation());
  dic.setContact(sap.getContact());
  dic.setDate(new PdfDate(sap.getSignDate()));
  sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
  HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
  exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(8192 * 2 + 2));
  sap.preClose(exc);
  // ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

  ExternalDigest externalDigest = new ExternalDigest() {

    @Override
    public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm) throws GeneralSecurityException {
      return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
    }
  };
  PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA1", null, externalDigest, false);
  InputStream data = sap.getRangeStream();
  byte hash[] = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest("RSA"));
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

  byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  session.setAttribute("sgn", sgn);
  session.setAttribute("hash", hash);
  session.setAttribute("cal", cal);
  session.setAttribute("sap", sap);
  session.setAttribute("baos", baos);
  OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
  os.write(sh, 0, sh.length);
  os.flush();
  os.close();   }
```

After signing the PDF the servlet is invoked once again from the applet to insert the signed hash in the resulting PDF **-->**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
PdfPKCS7 sgn = (PdfPKCS7) session.getAttribute("sgn");
byte[] hash = (byte[]) session.getAttribute("hash");
Calendar cal = (Calendar) session.getAttribute("cal");
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = (PdfSignatureAppearance) session.getAttribute("sap");
ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream) session.getAttribute("baos");
session.invalidate();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
int read;
byte[] data = new byte[256];
while ((read = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  baos.write(data, 0, read);
}
sgn.setExternalDigest(baos.toByteArray(), null, "RSA");
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
System.arraycopy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.length);
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
try {
  sap.close(dic2);
} catch (DocumentException e) {
  throw new IOException(e);
}
byte[] pdf = os.toByteArray();
//test save sign pdf
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/out1.pdf");
out.write(pdf);
out.close();
OutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
sos.write(pdf, 0, pdf.length);
sos.flush();
sos.close();
```

These are the versions of the libraries I used:

- itextpdf -> 5.5.6
- bcprov.jdk15on.1.54
- jdk1.7

Comment: The example in the white paper is outdated. It's much better to use the [DeferredSigning](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4#881-c4_09_deferredsigning.java) example.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a well-documented question!  I compensated with an up-vote.The book I wrote is outdated and it's not the OP's fault that he doesn't succeed in getting the book example to work. I simply don't have the time to write a revision of the book. With the example I mentioned in the previous comment, the problem can be solved (but I don't have time to elaborate; if I had, I'd rewrite the book).

Comment: Stuck in the same problem, I'm generating signature on client-side using hwcrypto.js and I'm sending it to the server to add it into pdf.
Thank you @BrunoLowagie for creating the white paper, it will be of great help if you can elaborate on DefferedSigning example, If you have time.

Comment: I made some progress using DeferredSigning example  
**Creating empty signature**  
I recieve public certificate from client, create empty signature, return hash
[link](https://pastebin.com/3GXgx37x)  

**Signing PDF**
I receive signed data from the client,
[link](https://pastebin.com/eaTfqEUT)  

But I'm getting ASN.1 Parsing error, when I open the PDF  

I don't have entire certificate chain, I just have 1 public certificate, do I need to build chain with CA Certificate?